# How to remove label from the right sidebar?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I want to remove the label from the right sidebar of Gmail. I have tried to find a way to remove unwanted labels from the sidebar and keep the sidebar cleaner by just having important labels there and when I press *More* then all of the labels should appear. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Hover over it—a small drop-down arrow will appear at the right of it
2. Click on the drop-down arrow
3. From the list, select **Hide** under **In label list:**

[image]

Comment: You can also do this all at once from the Label settings: https://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/labels